# Query foreign key data from Blade template

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `MenuCategory` and `MenuItem`, I want to display MenuItem data on my blade page along with its MenuCategory. I know its possible to do this by adding it to the return data in my controller however I would like to do it leveraging Eloquent instead, however I receive errors.

Here are my codes:

**MenuCategory model**

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MenuItem');
}
```

**MenuItem model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MenuCategory');
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $item = MenuItem::findOrFail($id);
    return view('menu.admin.single', compact('item'));
}
```

**Blade Page**

```
{{ $item->category->name }}
```

---

### UPDATE:

Table **menu_item**

```
id
name
menu_category_id
```

Table **menu_category**

```
id
name
```

When using all the above I get the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: did you try `{{ $item->category()->name }}`?

Comment: Yes, I get this error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

Comment: Perhaps do a `dd()` on your controller to see if your `$item` has a loaded `category`. Make sure you follow `Eloquent`'s table and foreign key naming conventions or explicitly declare your foreign keys when assigning `Eloquent` relationships.

Comment: How does the table structure look like? If you do not follow the Eloquent naming convention; that may cause some issues.

Comment: @JohnSvensson Please check updated post

Comment: Try $this->belongsTo('App\MenuCategory', 'menu_category_id');

Comment: @JohnSvensson That fixed it! Please convert to answer.

Comment: @Imran done glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to the naming convention of Eloquent.

Provide the optional foreign key variable in your relationship method to make it work, ie.

```
$this->belongsTo('App\MenuCategory', 'menu_category_id');
```

Comment: Isn't Laravel default naming convention to convert camelCase to snake_case exactly like that?

Comment: Eloquent also assumes that the table name is pluralized, in the docs: "Flight" model -> "flights"

Comment: So the table should probably be menu_categories instead.

Comment: Got it. +1 to catch that.

Answer (score 1):

Probably every `Item` doesn't contain a related category but to make sure you may try something like this, it'll try to retrieve the name only if there is a related category is available:

```
{{ $item->category ? $item->category->name : 'No Name or empty string' }}
```

Alternatively you may try something like this:

```
$item = MenuItem::has('category') // check if there is a related category
                ->with('category') // if yes then load it with that category
                ->findOrFail($id);
```

You used a different foreign key than `Laravel` expect so explicitly mention it like:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\MenuCategory', 'menu_category_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: This just returns the following error: `syntax error, unexpected 'No' (T_STRING)`. But I am certain every item has a valid foreign key attached, there is also foreign key constraints setup on the database to ensure this.

Comment: That should not throw any error but it's throwing syntax error so it means that you made some mistake/typo, try to find out the problem and for further debugging, check the `$item` from within the controller using `dd($item)` but load the `category` using `with` and `has/whereHas` method by checking it.